# How to add a tool to a GCC toolchain?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, gnu-assembler, toolchain

I am currently working on the toolchain for a processor that has been developed at my university. The processor is closely based on [OpenRISC](http://opencores.org/or1k/Main_Page) (orpsocv2 has been used as a baseline). Building programs for that platform requires that some custom instructions are added to the binary. I already implemented  tools that modify assembly code accordingly (utilizing regular expressions). However, I am looking for a way to integrate it with the [GNU toolchain of OpenRISC](http://opencores.org/wiki1/index.php?title=OpenRISC_GNU_tool_chain).

A regular toolchain consists of the following tools:
preprocessor -> compiler -> assembler -> linker

I need my adaptations to be integrated somewhere after compilation (because I require information about the basic blocks that will be present in the binary) and before linking (because afterwards things get messy when you try to change addresses).

Now my question: *Is there an easy way to add another tool between the compiler and the assembler of the GNU toolchain?*

I don't want to do that manually in the Makefile, because I would like to have the tools as compatible as possible to existing software projects.

So far, I haven't been able to find anything related in the GCC documentation or the web.

Comment: In the meantime, I stumbled across the section [Spec Files in the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Spec-Files.html#Spec-Files). This is probably the solution to my issue. However,  so far I haven't been able to utilize this successfully.